# Type 'ns1:Budget' is not validly derived from the type definition, 'Campaign', of element 'ns1:operand'

Tags: php, google-api, google-ads-api

Using this package for laravel: https://github.com/nikolajlovenhardt/laravel-google-ads

When i try to write a campaign, the following error occur:

> SoapFault in AdsSoapClient.php line 115: Unmarshalling Error:
>   cvc-elt.4.3: Type 'ns1:Budget' is not validly derived from the type
>   definition, 'Campaign', of element 'ns1:operand'.

soap.log: http://pastebin.com/raw/TmU6XSfp

> [2017-03-10 14:33:57] AW_SOAP.INFO: clientCustomerId=556-905-2150
>   operations=1 service=BudgetService method=mutate responseTime=145
>   requestId=00054a61407809890a378107c00d151f server=adwords.google.com
>   isFault=0 faultMessage=   [2017-03-10 14:33:58] AW_SOAP.WARNING:
>   clientCustomerId=556-905-2150 operations= service=CampaignService
>   method=mutate responseTime= requestId= server=adwords.google.com
>   isFault=1 faultMessage=Unmarshalling Error: cvc-elt.4.3: Type
>   'ns1:Budget' is not validly derived from the type definition,
>   'Campaign', of element 'ns1:operand'.    [2017-03-10 14:33:58]
>   AW_SOAP.NOTICE: POST /api/adwords/cm/v201609/CampaignService?wsdl
>   HTTP/1.1 Host: adwords.google.com Connection: Keep-Alive User-Agent:
>   PHP-SOAP/7.1.2-3+deb.sury.org~xenial+1 Content-Type: text/xml;
>   charset=utf-8 SOAPAction: "" Content-Length: 1436 Authorization:
>   REDACTED
>
> 556-905-2150REDACTEDunknown
>   (AwApi-PHP, googleads-php-lib/25.2.0,
>   PHP/7.1.2-3+deb.sury.org~xenial+1)falsefalseADDInterplanetary Cruise Budget
>
> ## 58c2b955417e250000000STANDARDADDInterplanetary Cruise
>
> ## 58c2b955cc997PAUSED1050511653DISPLAYMANUAL_CPC
>
> HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error Content-Type: text/xml;
>   charset=UTF-8 Date: Fri, 10 Mar 2017 14:33:58 GMT Expires: Fri, 10 Mar
>   2017 14:33:58 GMT Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
>   X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
>   X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block Server: GSE Alt-Svc: quic=":443";
>   ma=2592000; v="36,35,34" Accept-Ranges: none Vary: Accept-Encoding
>   Transfer-Encoding: chunked
>
> soap:ClientUnmarshalling
>   Error: cvc-elt.4.3: Type 'ns1:Budget' is not validly derived from the
>   type definition, 'Campaign', of element 'ns1:operand'.

Copied from the "Basic Operations Samples"

```
$customerClientId = 'xxx-xxx-xxxx';

$adWordsService = new AdWordsService();

/** @var BudgetService $budgetService */
$budgetService = $adWordsService->getService(BudgetService::class, $customerClientId);

// Create the shared budget (required).
$budget = new Budget();
$budget->setName('Interplanetary Cruise Budget #' . uniqid());
$money = new Money();
$money->setMicroAmount(50000000);
$budget->setAmount($money);
$budget->setDeliveryMethod(BudgetBudgetDeliveryMethod::STANDARD);

$operations = [];

// Create a budget operation.
$operation = new BudgetOperation();
$operation->setOperand($budget);
$operation->setOperator(Operator::ADD);
$operations[] = $operation;

// Create the budget on the server.
$result = $budgetService->mutate($operations);
$budget = $result->getValue()[0];

// Create a campaign with only required settings.
$campaign = new Campaign();
$campaign->setName('Interplanetary Cruise #' . uniqid());
$campaign->setAdvertisingChannelType(AdvertisingChannelType::DISPLAY);

// Set shared budget (required).
$campaign->setBudget(new Budget());
$campaign->getBudget()->setBudgetId($budget->getBudgetId());

// Set bidding strategy (required).
$biddingStrategyConfiguration = new BiddingStrategyConfiguration();
$biddingStrategyConfiguration->setBiddingStrategyType(
        BiddingStrategyType::MANUAL_CPC);
$campaign->setBiddingStrategyConfiguration($biddingStrategyConfiguration);

$campaign->setStatus(CampaignStatus::PAUSED);

// Create a campaign operation and add it to the operations list.
$operation = new CampaignOperation();
$operation->setOperand($campaign);
$operation->setOperator(Operator::ADD);
$operations[] = $operation;

/** @var CampaignService $campaignService */
$campaignService = $adWordsService->getService(CampaignService::class, $customerClientId);

$result = $campaignService->mutate($operations);

foreach ($result->getValue() as $campaign) {
    printf("Campaign with name '%s' and ID %d was added.\n",
        $campaign->getName(),
        $campaign->getId()
    );
}
```

Receiving campaigns with the sample code works...

Comment: are you sure that uses the Google PHP client library?   Have you considered contacting the author of the package on GitHub?

Comment: As you can see: https://github.com/nikolajlovenhardt/laravel-google-ads/blob/master/composer.json#L26

Comment: Yes I can see and that's googleads-php-lib not Google-api-php-client https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client  please remove invalid tag if this is the case

Comment: @DaImTo receiving campaigns works but creating one does not, so i don't think the problem is the package..

Comment: I think is a complaint from Soap because something failed at Google side, and Google answered in incorrect Soap terms. Or perhaps something is not well defined in the library, I get the same error from the Official google library trying to call a mutate method, but I'm conscious that I haven't already an approved developer key, so I have to wait.

NOTE: For your safety, please remove your clientCustomerID from the Soap log.

Answer (score 0):

I fink, it's because, you make  $campaignService->mutate($operations); with budget operation

```
$operations = [];
// Create a budget operation.
$operation = new BudgetOperation();
$operation->setOperand($budget);
$operation->setOperator(Operator::ADD);
$operations[] = $operation;
```

And

```
// Create a campaign operation and add it to the operations list.
$operation = new CampaignOperation();
$operation->setOperand($campaign);
$operation->setOperator(Operator::ADD);
$operations[] = $operation;

$result = $campaignService->mutate($operations);
```

You need to do $operations = []; again before $campaignService->mutate($operations);

```
$operations = [];
// Create a campaign operation and add it to the operations list.
$operation = new CampaignOperation();
$operation->setOperand($campaign);
$operation->setOperator(Operator::ADD);
$operations[] = $operation;

/** @var CampaignService $campaignService */
$campaignService = $adWordsService->getService(CampaignService::class, $customerClientId);
$result = $campaignService->mutate($operations);
```